# Flexbox child height it content

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have a container with display: flex, and it childs height, is higher than it content.
I'm using Vuetify (vuejs)

For example:

I have a v-col with 2 span

```html
<v-col style="display:flex;flex-direction:column">
  <span style="background-color:green;font-size:0.4rem">134 POSTS</span>
  <span style="background-color:green;font-size:0.4rem">120 POSTS</span>
</v-col>
```

If I put flex-direction to column, then:

[image]

height of spans is greater than it content!

If I put flex-direction to row, then:

[image]

the same happens.

I expect that the span height is only his content height

Edit:

I try again and the problem is only when I try to put inside display flex column inside a card: here is the code to try in vuetify

```html
<v-card>
  <v-card-title>
    <v-row>
      <v-col class="d-flex" style="flex-direction: column">
        <span style="font-size: 0.6rem"> 123123 </span>
        <span style="font-size: 0.6rem"> 123121 </span>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-card-title>
</v-card>
```

[image]

Solution:

I found the solution, v-card-title have a class with line-height, the solution is edit this line-height

[image]

[image]

Comment: Set a padding to 0

Comment: Your issue cannot be reproduced with the given code. Working perfectly fine on my side. Some other CSS is being applied to your blocks. Please check in your browser devtools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vuetify, `v-card-title` class has a `line-height: 2rem` set by default, editing this one fixed the issue!

[image]